# How to ensure diversity among results on Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

How to accomplish this - Within a given result-set, don't allow a group of docs with some common key to dominate the top ranks. Instead, limit or de-rank some of the group's docs such that they get a relatively lower score or omitted altogether from the result-set.
[Here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/misc/org/apache/lucene/search/DiversifiedTopDocsCollector.html) are the docs for a Lucene based solution `DiversifiedTopDocsCollector` with some example use cases.

Ways to implement something similar or an approximation of this ability on Azure Cognitive Search?

Comment: Maybe @Yhanoosh?